# LNK2019, boost::asio

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, boost, boost-asio

In visual studio 2010, I get

> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall
>   Server::Server(class boost::asio::io_service &)"
>   (??0Server@@QAE@AAVio_service@asio@boost@@@Z) referenced in the
>   function _main    C:\Users\Lucie\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\Expérimentation Serveur\Expérimentation
>   Serveur\Main_Serveur.obj

However, I have the class definition in the header file and the class implementation in the .cpp file both included in the solution, so I really don't see why I'm getting this. Furthermore, I have checked, and the definition and declaration seem to match.

Here is Main_Serveur.cpp:

```
include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <hash_map>
#include <functional>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <hash_set>

#include "Connection.h"
#include "Server.h"

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
int main()
{
    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        Server server(io_service);
        io_service.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is Server.h:

```
#ifndef __SERVER_H__
#define __SERVER_H__
#include"Connection.h"
#include<boost\bind.hpp>
#include<boost\asio.hpp>
#include<boost\shared_ptr.hpp>
#include<boost\enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include<hash_set>
#include<string>
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class Connection;
class Server : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Server>
{
public:
    Server(boost::asio::io_service & io_service);
    void removeSocketFromList(tcp::socket * socketToRemove);
    void sendToList(std::string message);
    void addSocketToList(tcp::socket * newSocket);

private:
    void start_accept();
    void handle_accept
    (
        boost::shared_ptr<Connection> new_connection,
        const boost::system::error_code& error
    );


    std::hash_set<tcp::socket*> sockets_;
    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
};
#endif
```

And here is the relevant part of Server.cpp:

```
#include"Server.h"
#include"Connection.h"

#include<boost\asio.hpp>
#include<hash_set>
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

Server::Server(boost::asio::io_service & io_service):
acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 13))
{
    start_accept();
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `boost::asio` is one of the (few) Boost libraries which must actually be built. It isn't header only -- you'll have to build the components you need and configure Visual Studio so that it can find the bits.

Comment: Try following section 5 of the Boost getting started guide: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#prepare-to-use-a-boost-library-binary

Comment: boost::asio is compiled and worked fine for a while. I'm not convinced that boost::asio is the cause of the problem. The software worked fine for a while, until new additions to the structure made it stop working. I don't see how those additions are relevant though; they involve mostly adding organizing socket pointers into hashsets - hardly relevant to linkers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up creating a new project and including the sources and headers, and the project compiled.
Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

It must because of you wouldn't have compiled Server.cpp. Instead you compiled Main_serveur.cpp file only. This time the linker does not see the Server.obj and this pops up link error like you've gotten (undefined copy constructor). You either create project add all files to it (like you did) or compile cpp files which are left to be compiled separatley to generate its objs. Also, you could use makefile, which is better than the other two options.